# How to properly sort a set of axis-aligned boxes so they are drawn correctly under this projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, matrices, algebraic-geometry, trigonometry

Given a set S of axis-aligned, non-overlapping boxes {x,y,z,w,h,l}, where x,y,z are their center-positions and w,h,l their width, height and lengths, and given the following orthographic projection:

```
proj_x = x - z*sqrt(2)/2
proj_y = y - z*sqrt(2)/2
```

What is a function f(a,b) that determines wheter box A is above (and, thus, should be drawn after) B under that projection?

[image]

Comment: If you have two boxes with the same center, but one has $(w_1,h_1,l_1)=(2,2,2)$ and the other has $(w_2,h_2,l_2)=(3,1,1)$, then neither one fully overlaps the other. So, drawing one and then the other won't look right. What should be done in such cases?

Comment: @ChrisCulter Oh, I should've specified that no box ever overlaps.

Comment: Ah, okay! I think there's still a bad case involving three boxes. Just a minute...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a potential problem. You can have three thin boxes with different long axes that occlude each other in a rock-paper-scissors manner, i.e. non-transitively:

[image: Three lines]

If you like, the boxes can be made short enough so that they just barely occlude each other; they don't have to fully cross. What should happen then?

Comment: Great input, that makes sense. I guess the problem is more complicated than I thought. Yet, for most of the cases there is a way to sort them that "makes sense", such as that image. I just don't know how to implement/formalize that. Do you have an insight?

Comment: @Dokkat I'm afraid I don't have a particular insight. You could read up on the painter's algorithm to see what solutions are available. But since you have a fixed perspective, you probably don't need the full power of the methods used in 3D graphics. It seems like there might be a simple solution... I'm just not sure what that is!